# Making pre-existent Gmail labels into sub-labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have two Gmail labels, "Basketball" and "Student Council". My question is this: How do I make both of these labels into sub-labels of another label, "Extracurricular"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to *Settings* (the cog wheel in the upper-right corner) → *Labels* → click **Edit** for the respective label → click **Nest label under** and select the respective label under you wish to nest it (“Extracurricular” in your case) → click **Save**. Of course, you should create the “Extracurricular” label first.